# equivalent development/build tools for suse professional 11

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have suse professional 11.4

In redhat we have this:

```
yum group install "development tools"
```

In Debian we have this:

```
apt-get install build-essentials
```

What is the equivalent for suse? I want to install all the build/developer tools.

Many thanks for any suggesions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this on the Suse forum.

http://forums.opensuse.org/applications/413553-build-essential.html

There is no 'build essential' type package - You can install c/c++ dev tools with the command `zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++` or by installing either the `C/C++ Compiler and Tools` (on suse 11.0) or `C/C++ Development` pattern from YAST Software management

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jeroen's answer, i ran this command to find out the pattern name:

```
$ zypper se -t pattern devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name        | Summary                  | Type
--+-------------+--------------------------+--------
i | Basis-Devel | C/C++ Compiler and Tools | pattern
```

Then it was a matter of installing the packages:

```
$ zypper install --type pattern Basis-Devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following NEW packages are going to be installed:
  adaptec-firmware aspell aspell-en aspell-ispell atmel-firmware autoconf automake bison brocade-firmware ctags cvs emacs emacs-info emacs-x11 flex gcc43-c++ gcc43-info gcc43-locale gcc-c++ gcc-info gcc-locale gdbm-devel giflib
  glibc-info icom-firmware ipw-firmware kernel-default-devel kernel-source libaio-devel libasound2 libncurses6 libstdc++43-devel libstdc++-devel mpt-firmware ncurses-devel pkg-config rcs tack texinfo xaw3d

The following NEW patterns are going to be installed:
  Basis-Devel Minimal

<snip>
```

This was on SLES SP1.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, in openSUSE Tumbleweed, there is something similar to "development tools" from fedora.
Basically you run this:

`sudo zypper in -y --type pattern devel_basis devel_C_C++`

In order to check the availalbe groups you can run this command:

```
$ sudo zypper se -t pattern devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                 | Summary                                     | Type
---+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------
i+ | devel_basis          | Base Development                            | pattern
i+ | devel_C_C++          | C/C++ Development                           | pattern
   | devel_gnome          | GNOME Development                           | pattern
   | devel_java           | Java Development                            | pattern
   | devel_kde_frameworks | KDE Frameworks and Plasma Development       | pattern
   | devel_kernel         | Linux Kernel Development                    | pattern
   | devel_mono           | .NET Development                            | pattern
   | devel_osc_build      | Tools for Packaging with Open Build Service | pattern
   | devel_perl           | Perl Development                            | pattern
   | devel_python3        | Python 3 Developement                       | pattern
   | devel_qt5            | Qt 5 Development                            | pattern
   | devel_qt6            | Qt 6 Development                            | pattern
   | devel_rpm_build      | RPM Build Environment                       | pattern
   | devel_ruby           | Ruby Development                            | pattern
   | devel_tcl            | Tcl/Tk Development                          | pattern
   | devel_vulkan         | Vulkan Development                          | pattern
   | devel_web            | Web Development                             | pattern
   | devel_yast           | YaST Development                            | pattern
   | hpc_development_node | HPC Development Packages                    | pattern
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).